# How can I clean code in CSS using WebStorm

Tags: css, webstorm

Is there any way to clean code on WebStorm?

I mean like this

before clean

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1e1939;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
}
```

after clean

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #1e1939;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

If you use Android Studio you will understand me when press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + Alt</kbd> in XML.

Comment: What's cleaner about the second one? All you've done is rearrange the order of some of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Code Style CSS option to configure formatting options for your css files, take a look at:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-code-style-css.html

Take a look at the "Arrangement" part.

Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + S</kbd>

Comment: It's not plugin ?